# Can I have a form input that doesn't get serialized/submitted on form submission without JS?

Tags: html

Let's say I have a form like this:

```
<form id="something_form">
  <input type="text" id="thing1" name="thing1">
  <input type="hidden" id="thing2" name="thing2">
  <input type="text" id="secret" name="secret">

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Currently I have JS that listens for the submission event, takes the info in the `secret` input, and does some work before adding it to `thing2`. The server never uses or needs `secret`. I can clear the data in `secret` before form submission, so it's just `thing1=abc&thing2=abc&secret=`, however if the user has JS off, then the form submission request would have `thing1=abc&thing2=&secret=secret`.

Is there a pure HTML way to make an input work as normal, but not get serialized/submitted on form submission? I know that I can remove `name="secret"` to achieve this, but that loses me any functionality that relies on the `name` attribute.

My idea for a solution is to render the page without the `name="secret"`:

```
<input type="text" id="secret">
```

then add it via JS(since if the user has JS on, it would run):

```
document.getElementById("secret").setAttribute("name", "secret");
```

But I'm curious if there's another solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the `form` attribute.  An input with the `form` attribute  set counts as part of the form whose ID matches its `form` attribute, NOT as part of the form that it's actually inside of.

Example: `<input type="text" name="fish" form="bogus">` won't get submitted along with the rest of the form, unless the form has `id="bogus"` for some reason.

Comment: One comment on the linked duplicate did mention that this is (or was) invalid HTML. That's probably not a practical concern, but you might also look at omitting the name attribute, which apparently accomplishes the same goal.

Comment: Omitting the `name` entirely causes issues with existing JS libs I'm using, which is why I thought rendering without `name` attr, but adding the `name` attr on page load via JS would solve it, but I usually prefer a non-JS solution if possible. So this is much better than my solution.